# how to get words highlighted as soon as they are typed in Android

Tags: android

I want the **EditText** area to work the way the **textView** is working when I am typing let it highlight some specific word like the way the **textView** works. This code is what I did but its not working when I type it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.span_test);
    String str = " This is as a result of instances in this matter and "
            + "as it is has look as this. So and this3 goes on manthis "
            +"and also thisman like this gen ,";
    String regex = "\\bthis\\b";
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.span_test);
    SpannableString spstr = new SpannableString(str);
    Pattern patern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(spstr.toString());
    while(matcher.find()){
        spstr.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View wiget){
                Toast.makeText(SpanTestActivity.this,
                        "Clicked" + "styledString. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            };}, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
    textView.setText(spstr);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.span_test1);
    spstr = new SpannableString(editText.toString());
    patern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    matcher = patern.matcher(spstr.toString());
    while(matcher.find()){
        spstr.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View wiget){
                Toast.makeText(SpanTestActivity.this,
                        "Clicked" + "styledString. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            };}, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
        editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
    editText.setText(spstr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TextWatcher ()`

You can found the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Because what do you want to do is found a specific word when the user is typing. 
TextWatcher is always listen the changes inside the TexView. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for TextView

So you need to do is the next:

```
youtTextView.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)
```

Comment: I tried but didn't get what I wanted I'll post the question again with what I did